# Failing to query from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a count of occurrences of a value from my database. It's failing.

My effort is

```
        var dc = new Dal.Entities();
        var query = (from d in dc.Instruments
                      where d.Src.ToLower().Contains("other.png")
                      select new
                      {
                          count = d.Src.Count(),
                          key = d.Src
                      }
                      );
```

This keeps throwing the following exception

```
"DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.\r\nParameter name: input"
```

If I change `select new...` to `select d` then it works fine so I know that part of the query is OK.

I don't understand why I can't get a Count of each string it finds. What did I do wrong?

*edit*

If my database is

```
Src (column title)
my value
my other value
my value
```

I'm hoping to get the result of

```
my value, 2
my other value, 1
```

Comment: try `d.Src.Length` instead

Comment: The `where` part will filter all your data and you will remain only with `other.png` so a simple `Count` at the end will work. Why need the `Group`?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to count. The current code is trying (unsuccessfully) to get the count of the characters in the `Src` field matching the filter.

Comment: @IvanStoev, updated my post

Comment: I see. Then you need simple `group by`.

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes, that has worked. Can you post the answer please

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped. But @octavioccl already posted it, it makes no sense to duplicate it, please feel free to accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by then:

```
     var query = from d in dc.Instruments
                  where d.Src.ToLower().Contains("other.png")
                  group d by d.Src into g
                  select new
                  {
                      count = g.Count(),
                      key = g.Key
                  };
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the length of a string, but the amount of time that string occurs in the database. I will udpate my post as its clearly written badly

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = dc.Instruments
    .Where(p => p.Src.ToLower().Contains("other.png"))
    .Count();
```

or

```
var items = (from item in dc.Instruments
             where item.Src.ToLower().Contains("other.png")
             select item).Count();
```